# How to properly register a component in a Vue 3 + Composition API app?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to build an app with two layout, one with header and everything, one with just the background for some special pages(like login pages).

I've tried the following:

Created 2 view page:

`layouts/Default.vue`

```html
<template>
   <header class="flex justify-around">
      <Header class="w-10/12 max-w-screen-lg"></Header>
   </header>

   <div class="grow h-full flex justify-around">
      <div class="bg-white m-5 rounded-lg p-3 w-10/12 max-w-screen-lg shadow-lg">
         <slot />
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Header from "../components/Header.vue";
</script>
```

and

`layouts/Plain.vue`

```html
<template>
   <div class="grow h-full flex justify-around">
      <div class="bg-white m-5 rounded-lg p-3 w-10/12 max-w-screen-lg shadow-lg">
         <slot />
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

In my router/index.ts, I provide a "meta"

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginView,
      meta: { layout: 'plain' },
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue'),
    },
  ],
});
```

In my `App.vue`: I try to use this  to create a component that wraps my routerView:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from "vue";
import { RouterView, useRoute } from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();

const layout = computed(() => {
  return (route.meta.layout || 'default');
});
</script>

<template>
  <div id="root"
       class="min-h-full bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500 flex flex-col">
    <component :is="layout">
      <RouterView></RouterView>
    </component>

  </div>
</template>
```

And more important, in my `main.ts` file, I did try to register them:

```js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import Vue, { createApp } from 'vue';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

import './assets/main.css';
import Plain from './layouts/Plain.vue';
import Default from './layouts/Default.vue';


const app = createApp(App);

app.component('default', Default);
app.component('plain', Plain)

app.use(createPinia());
app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

But when I try to display ANY page, I get this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=7cc2bcdd' does not provide an export named 'default' (at main.ts:2:8)
```

So I guess, that `app.component('vue-name', component)` is not the correct approach, but I can't find how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is unrelated to your component registration, but rather it points to this:

```js
        // The requested module 'vue.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
import Vue, { createApp } from 'vue';
```

In Vue 3, the `vue` module has no `default` export, so `import Vue from 'vue'` would fail. The `Vue` import also isn't used anywhere in `main.ts`, so you apparently don't even need it. The solution is to remove it:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'; ✅
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-router-layout-meta?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Damned! You're right, I've copied some imports from some tutorial that was in 2.0. This "default" really made me thing it was my layout name. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

According to [official docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#dynamic-components) you should import them inside the `App.vue` and use them as variables :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from "vue";
import { RouterView, useRoute } from "vue-router";
import Plain from '../layouts/Plain.vue';
import Default from '../layouts/Default.vue';

const route = useRoute();

const layout = computed(() => {
  return route.meta.layout==='plain'? Plain : Default;
});
</script>

<template>
  <div id="root"
       class="min-h-full bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-500 via-purple-500 to-pink-500 flex flex-col">
    <component :is="layout">
      <RouterView></RouterView>
    </component>

  </div>
</template>
```

You could use normal script without setup to get globally registered components, by using vite try out [vite-plugin-vue-layouts](https://github.com/JohnCampionJr/vite-plugin-vue-layouts) to register your layouts dynamically.